# how to pass parameters along with rest operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

Following is my function call:

```
await this.faqs({'fields.page': page, ...filters});
```

and function is:

```
async faqs({state, commit}, filters) {

const {items} = await fetchData({content_type: state.contentType, ...filters});

const faqs = items.map((item) => {
  return {
    id: item.systemId,
    ...item.fields,
  };
});

commit('setFaqs', faqs);

return faqs;}
```

I want to pass two more parameters along with this rest operator. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think your code snippets do what you think they do.

Comment: if the function is `async faqs({ state, commit }, filters) { ... }` then there is no rest parameter; `filters` seems to be an array maybe? so the calls looks like `this.faqs({ state: ..., commit: ... }, [ ... ])` where `[...]` is an array of filters of you can pass. hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: @Thankyou , I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

create an object and let it have 2 named keys and they use then use the spread operator for filters , like so:

```
await this.faqs({'fields.page': page, param1: 'someparam1', param2: 'someparam2', ...filters });
```

Comment: `{a: 1, {b: 2, c: 3}}` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Olian04 took off the brackets , hope thats fine

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik,  How can I access it in function?

Comment: @Trupti  `async faqs({state, commit}, param1, param2, filters) ` like so, try it and let me know

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, in console.log(param1);... it gives output as {'fields.page': page, param1: 'someparam1', param2: 'someparam2'} ... and console.log(filters) as undefined